# How to Destroy a Grid and Create a New One

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm new to this site so please forgive me if I am doing this wrong. I am working on a project and we are trying to make a version of Minesweeper that will have specific mines and make constellation shapes.

We are trying to make it seem like levels where if the player wins they go to the next level. The only problem is that in our win function we cannot figure out how to create a new grid with the new mines and delete the old grid without it stacking or destroying the whole frame.

You can get the image files from our github account:https://github.com/Riddler6897/Star-Minesweeper

It also has the most updated code is in the file called `TestRun.py` and all the images are in the `images` folder.

Here everyone's convenience, here are the four .gif images:

plaintile.gif: [image: plaintile.gif]
clickedtile.gif: [image: clickedtile.gif]
minetile.gif: [image: minetile.gif]
flagtile.gif: [image: flagtile.gif]

```
from Tkinter import * #We could also use pygame#
from time import time #To set a timer#
from time import sleep #To make the RGBs turn on and off#
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
class Minesweeper(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.images = [PhotoImage(file = "images/plaintile.gif"),
                       PhotoImage(file = "images/clickedtile.gif"),
                       PhotoImage(file = "images/minetile.gif"),
                       PhotoImage(file = "images/flagtile.gif")]
        self.NoTile = []
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
#populates NoTile with images corresponding to the number of mines adjacent to each tile
        #for x in range (1,9):
            #self.NoTile.append(PhotoImage(file = "images/tile_"+str(x)+".gif"))

        self.button = []
#arrays containing the position of each mine that will make the shape of the constellations
        self.Libra = [23, 63, 102, 124, 154, 161, 197, 209]
        self.Orion = [0, 2, 16, 30, 62, 66, 73, 89, 93, 103, 113, 118, 125, 132, 139, 146, 153, 211, 217]
        self.Phoenix = [22, 44, 45, 78, 85, 121, 148, 169, 203]
        self.Taurus = [3, 30, 35, 64, 67, 83, 95, 99, 113, 129, 146, 163, 178, 204, 223]
        self.CanisMajor = [21, 49, 69, 73, 81, 101, 140, 144, 186, 197, 203, 212]
        self.Draco = [32, 51, 63, 67, 96, 127, 157, 161, 167, 173, 193, 195, 198, 212, 224]
        self.CanesVenatici = [42, 182]
        self.Chameleon = [66, 104, 106, 133, 140]
        self.Crater = [4, 22, 98, 120, 142, 153, 164, 220]
        self.Vulpecula = [2, 51, 61, 83, 114, 145, 178, 209]
        self.levels = [self.CanesVenatici, self.Chameleon, self.Libra, self.Crater, self.Vulpecula, self.Phoenix, self.CanisMajor, self.Taurus, self.Draco, self.Orion]
#an array containing all the constellations in order of "difficulty"
        self.level = 0
        self.score = 1
        self.pressed = 0
        self.tiles = 225-len(self.levels[self.level])
#labels showing the current level and the number of mines in the level        
        self.label1 = Label(master, text = "Mines: "+str(len(self.levels[self.level])))
        self.label1.grid(row = 16, column = 0, columnspan = 5)
        self.label2 = Label(master, text = "Level: "+ str(self.score))
        self.label2.grid(row = 16, column = 5, columnspan = 5)
        self.label3 = Label(master, text = "Tiles Left: "+str(self.pressed))
        self.label3.grid(row = 16, column = 10, columnspan = 5)



    def buttonPressed(self, i):
        self.pressed += 1
        self.tiles -= 1
        self.label3 = Label(self.master, text = "Tiles Left: "+str(self.tiles))
        self.label3.grid(row = 16, column = 10, columnspan = 5)
        self.button[i].config(image = self.images[1], state=DISABLED)
        if self.tiles == 200:
            self.win()

    def minePressed(self, i):
        self.button[i].config(image=self.images[2])
        #self.lose()

    def constellation_plot(self):
        for i in self.levels[self.level]:
            self.button[i].config(command = lambda i=i: self.minePressed(i))

    #def update_mine(self):
        #pass

    def win(self):
        self.master.grid_forget()
        self.score += 1
        self.level += 1
        self.pressed = 0
        self.tiles = 225-len(self.levels[self.level])
        self.grid()



    def grid(self): #This will make the grid#
        i = 0
        for r in range(15):
            for c in range(15):
                self.mGrid = Button(self.master, image=self.images[0], command = lambda i=i :self.buttonPressed((i)))
                self.button.append(self.mGrid)
                self.mGrid.image = self.images[0]
                self.mGrid.grid(row=r, column=c)
                i += 1

        self.constellation_plot()


    def play(): #Will actually run the game#
        pass

    #def lose(self): #Will use GPIO for RGBs and allow the player to start the same level over#
        #quit(1)


    def time_out(): #timer. When the time goes out, the whole program will stop running while still showing score.#
        pass

    def sound(): #To play a sound if they win or lose. Can be put under the lose function#
        pass

window = Tk()
minesweeper = Minesweeper(window)
window.title("Minesweeper")
minesweeper.grid()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: In order for anyone else to try running your code it would be helpful it they had copies of the 4 `.gif` images being referenced. Since you can't embed them in your question yet, I suggest to upload each of them to one of the free online image sharing sites, such as http://imgur.com, and add links to them in your question.

Comment: Will sending the link to our github account work?

Comment: Yes, I think so, [edit] your question and add the link.

Comment: Have yoy tried simply deleting the old widgets? The method for destroying a widget is documented, and there are many examples on the web.

Comment: Why do you want to delete them? why don't you just update them to whatever new state you want them in?

Comment: We were probably going about it the wrong way but there was a strange error where it would recreate the grid on top of the old grid so we thought that deleting the old grid might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some other issues, but to answer your question, you can add a `remove_button_grid()` method to the class and call it in the `win()` function using `self.remove_button_grid` (instead of the `self.master.grid_forget()` you currently have in your code.

This is what the new method should look like:

```
    def remove_button_grid(self):
        while self.button:
            button = self.button.pop()
            button.destroy()
```

By the way, I think `self.buttons` would be a better name for the list of buttons attribute. Also, I think you should rename the `Minesweeper` class' `grid()` method something else, since that's the name of a layout manager method it inherited from `Frame` and does something completely different from the one defined in the subclass because not doing so can confuse folks familiar with `Tkinter`—as it did me until it indirectly came up in a comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping us with this! It completely solved our issue. I really appreciate all the very fast and helpful responses

Comment: I wouldn't name it `grid_forget`, since that clashes with the  built-in function names. While it will work, it will lead to confusing code since most people who read it won't expect `grid_forget` to actually destroy a widget instead of just forgetting it.

Comment: @Bryan:  Excellent point—and generally sound advice. Besides that it's a terrific segue to a related, although somewhat off-question-topic subject. Class `Minesweeper`, a `Tkinter.Frame` subclass, defines its own `grid()` method which has nothing to do with the `Tkinter` layout manager of the same name. That fact, ironically (and proving the point perfectly), led me to forget about the `Tkinter` layout manager's method when I wrote the code in my answer. So an even better point is what you say also being applied to the existing `Minesweeper.grid()` method.